# What is the best of loading bootstrapped backbone models into browserify

Tags: backbone.js, browserify

When using backbone with browserify what is the best way of [bootstrapping models](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap) so that you can inject into your app?

I tried to set a global object in the html but still can't seem to access that from inside the js.

Am I missing something? How is the best way of getting all the preseed data in?

Comment: Your asking two different questions :). Your approach is a good one, please show some code so that we can see what's wrong

Comment: Eric I asked something quite similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269359/inject-data-in-a-browserify-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is related to backbone but rather to all Browserify projects :)

The global variable solution works for us so it should work for you too: try again or give us your code :)

I didn't find any other way to do this except with a global variable.
I asked something quite similar here to know if there's a better way: [Inject data in a Browserify app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269359/inject-data-in-a-browserify-app)