# Inject data in a Browserify app

Tags: javascript, browserify, bootstrapping

Anyone here knows how to inject data into a Browserify app?

I mean, I use Browserify to create a big bundle app.js file.

But when my single page application starts, the server also add some bootstrap data into the HTML page that loads the app, so that the app doesn't have to do ajax requests to the server to get these data.

For now the HTML template rendered by the server to start the app looks like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
window.bootstrapData = @Html(utils.CustomSerializer.serialize(bootstrapData));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@{reactAppBaseUrl}/app.js"></script>
```

And inside `app.js` (the Browserified single page app), we are using the `window.bootstrapData` to get that data inside the Browserify bundle.

Is there any elegant way to do this that would not involve a global variable?

Comment: You could make a function instead, but that would then just be a global function. But FWIW, globals aren't always evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [external require](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-requires).

When you bundle your app, use the -r option to enable external requiring for a specific service:

```
browserify -r appBootstrap  > app.js
```

Then, in a script tag below where you've imported your bundle, require the service and inject the data:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@{reactAppBaseUrl}/app.js"></script>

<script>
  var serializedData = @Html(utils.CustomSerializer.serialize(bootstrapData))
  require('appBootstrap').load(serializedData);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks it works fine. But couldn't make it work the `expose` option,  any idea how it works?

Comment: I was able to get the expose option to work at both command line and using API, here is [gist](https://gist.github.com/majgis/433fe8cc89a1b50a24b4).

Comment: I get it working only when using as expose name the same name (i mean using require `app.js` with expose `app`, but I get an error when using another string than `app` which seems weird

Comment: I'm using browserify 6.3.2, maybe you have an older version with defect?